# Light particles/Light streaks effect

Tags: cycles-render-engine, geometry-nodes, lighting, simulation-nodes

I am trying to recreate an animation seen here:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eTes6yYH4iU

However, I am unable to recreate the light lines seen in the video. I have achieved similar to wanted results in EEVEE, but I would like to do it in cycles. Example from Eevee:

[image]

I was wondering, how should I approach the problem to make it happen in Cycles.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you provide your Blender file using https://blend-exchange.com/, so others can start from the results you achieved already ? And could you describe what you would like to reproduce from the linked video, instead of leaving others to identify key features ? You are mentioning an animation, but show a static picture.